# Need code to replace all words in a text file which ends with Characters KB

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a text file which has certain strings like 12344KB, 1231232KB etc.
I have to change these words which ends with KB to 10KB using powershell.
I just started to learn powershell , It would be really helpfull if someone can help me to provide script.

I tried something like below code.

```
((Get-Content -path C:\test.txt) -replace '*KB','10KB') | Set-Content -Path C:\test.txt
```

Actual: Values are  12344KB, 1231232KB

expected: values are 10KB, 10KB

Comment: Try `-replace '\b\d+KB\b', '10KB'`.

Comment: @Theo maybe submit that as an answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You're right. Too many questions are answered in comments

Answer (score 1):

To post my comment as answer (so the question no longer is 'Unanswered')

Try the following regex:

```
((Get-Content -path C:\test.txt) -replace '\b\d+KB\b', '10KB') | Set-Content -Path C:\test.txt
```